# Is there way to tell apart patterns with space and without, in Spacy NLP

Tags: regex, spacy

I am creating a pattern for a stock symbol ($APPL)

my best guess is

```
{"label": "STOCK", "pattern": [{'LEMMA': '$'}, {'IS_ALPHA': True, 'LENGTH': {"<": 7}}]
```

but this pattern picks up also strings like

*10$ APPLE*

is there a way to keep $ with alpha characters as one token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question from the title: Yes, you can tell if a token ends with space by using `SPACY`. You can add this in your example:

```
{"label": "STOCK", "pattern": [{'LEMMA': '$', "SPACY": False}, {'IS_ALPHA': True, 'LENGTH': {"<": 7}}]
```

Here's the list of all possible attributes: [Available Token Attributes](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#adding-patterns-attributes)